# Find total number of odd length substrings

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to write a function that calculates the total number of odd-length substrings in a given string. For example, for the string "abcde", the output should be 9, considering substrings of odd length only ([a, abc, abcde, b, bcd, c, cde, d, e]). Similarly, for the string "aaa", the output should be 4 ([a, aaa, a, a]). I'd appreciate any insights on how to efficiently implement this in java.

I am not able to come up with an efficient solution.

```
public static int countOddLengthSubstrings(String s) {
        int count = 0;
        int n = s.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
                if ((j - i + 1) % 2 != 0) { // Checking if length is odd
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Think about it: Does anything other than the length of the string matter for this? What changes to the length will result in more or less "odd" substrings? Can you see a pattern for the first few such lengths?

Comment: @tobias_k Please check my answer. I have come up with a solution which takes O(n) time.

Answer (score 10):

If all you care about is the number of odd length substrings, no deduplications, then the problem can be solved in O(1) time.

Consider string `"abcde"`. Let's only focus on substrings that start with the first character, in our case `"a"`. There are 3 odd length substrings: `"a"`, `"abc"`, and `"abcde"`.

Now let's focus on substrings starting with the second character, `"b"` here. An analogous question is how many odd length substrings starting with the first character are there in the string `"bcde"`? And we see there are `"b"` and `"bcd"`. For the third character, we have `"c"` and `"cde"`, and for the fourth and fifth we have `"d"` and `"e"` respectively.

I believe we can already see some pattern here. For a string with length `n`, the number of odd length substrings starting with the first character is `ceil(n/2)`. So the sequence would be `0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, ...`, starting from `n=0` (which is essentially [A004526](https://oeis.org/A004526)). Finding the total number of odd length substrings is then the partial sum of this sequence, which, per the OEIS (Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences), would be `floor((n+1)^2 / 4)`.

```java
public static int countOddLengthSubstrings(String s) {
    int n = s.length();
    return (n+1)*(n+1)/4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error I came up with the following code.

```
public static int countOddLengthSubstrings(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    int length = s.length();
        
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i+=2)
        count++;
  
    return count * count + (length % 2 == 0? length / 2 : 0);
}
```

I tried it and it worked, so I really don't know the logical way to explain it. But here's what the code does-

We start by finding the split points. In "abcde" that would be a, c and e.

**If the number is odd**, the square of the length of the split points returns the number of substrings.

**If the number is even**, the square of the length of the the split points added with the length of half the string returns the number of substrings.

Comment: Now look at the inner loop and think about the fact that adding one to a value n times is the same as just adding n one time. Once you got rid of that loop, look at the result and think if you can reduce the operations further, i.e. are there things that don’t change during the outer loop?

Comment: I was heading at the possibility to replace your inner loop `for (int j = i; j < length; j++) count++;` with `count += (length - i);` When you now extract the constant parts out of the loop, you’ll find that the only non-constant part is the `-i`, and you’re performing `(length + 1) / 2` (outer) iterations, summing up ascending numbers from zero to that number of iterations (times minus two). Use the well known trick for summing ascending numbers and you got rid of the outer loop too.

Comment: Then, after applying basic expression simplification you end up at `int length = s.length(), outerIterations = (length + 1) / 2; return outerIterations * (length - outerIterations + 1);`

Comment: @Holger I was messing around and this is what I came with, it works.

Comment: Well, yes, but you still can replace the remaining loop (`for (int i = 0; i < length; i+=2) count++;`) with `count = (length + 1) / 2;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, In this implementation, the countOddLengthSubstrings function iterates through each character in the string and calls the countOddLengthAtCenter function for each character. The countOddLengthAtCenter function counts the odd-length substrings centered at the given index using the two-pointer approach.

```
public static int countOddLengthSubstrings(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    int n = s.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // Count odd-length substrings centered at index i
        count += countOddLengthAtCenter(s, i);
    }

    return count;
}

private static int countOddLengthAtCenter(String s, int center) {
    int count = 0;
    int left = center;
    int right = center;

    // Count odd-length substrings
    while (left >= 0 && right < s.length()) {
        count++;
        left--;
        right++;
    }

    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "abcde";
    System.out.println(countOddLengthSubstrings(str1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for(int i = 2; i < n ; i++)`: Iterates over the indices of the string starting from 2, as the base cases are already initialized for strings of lengths 0, 1, and 2.

`dp[i+1] = dp[i] + i/2 + 1;`: Calculates the count of odd-length substrings for the current position i. It adds the count of odd-length substrings from the previous position `dp[i]`, and then adds `(i/2 + 1)` to account for the additional odd-length substrings introduced by including the current character at index `i`.

```
public static int count(String s){
    int n = s.length();
    if(n==0 || n==1 || n ==2) return n;
    int[] dp = new int[n+1];
    dp[0] = 0;
    dp[1] = 1;
    dp[2] = 2;
    for(int i = 2; i < n ; i++){
        dp[i+1] = dp[i] + i/2 + 1;
    }
    return dp[n];
}
```

Comment: bit different: `dp[i+1] = dp[i-1] + i + 1;` or even `for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) dp[i] = dp[i-2] + i;`

Answer (score 0):

Explanations after the code:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = "aaa";
        int len = s.length();
        int lim = len % 2 == 0 ? len - 1 : len;
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= lim; i += 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j + i <= len; j++) {
                total++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

The outer `for` loop is the length of the substrings to look for. First you look for substrings of length 1 (one), then substrings of length 3, then substrings of length 5, etc. The outer `for` loop terminates when the substring length is greater than the length of the source string.

The inner `for` loop iterates the characters in the source string. If the index of the character plus the length of the substring is less than the length of the source string, the total is incremented.

Of-course you can replace the source string, i.e. `aaa` in the above code, with any string that you like, e.g. `abcde`.